# TableView cells keep changing order

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Something weird is happening with a timer app I am making:

Every 0.25 seconds I update each cell's contents, but I sometimes get this weird glitch/bug (the table view cells keep changing order):

https://streamable.com/tta56

**Code that updates timer:**

Timer:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(processTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

processTimer() function:

```
@objc func processTimer() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TimersData")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        var i = 0
        if results.count > 0 {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let activityIndicator = result.value(forKey: "activity") as? String {
                    if activityIndicator == "active" {
                        if let startDate = result.value(forKey: "startDate") as? Date {
                            var seconds = startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
                            seconds = seconds * -1
                            if let timerSeconds = result.value(forKey: "timerSeconds") as? Int {
                                if let timerProgress = result.value(forKey: "timerProgress") as? Double {
                                    var newSeconds: Double = timerProgress - seconds
                                    if newSeconds < 0 {
                                        newSeconds = 0
                                    }
                                    result.setValue(newSeconds, forKey: "timerProgress")
                                    let now = Date()
                                    result.setValue(now, forKey: "startDate")
                                    do {
                                        try context.save()
                                    }
                                    catch {
                                        print("error")
                                    }
                                    result.setValue(Date(), forKey: "startDate")
                                    // TEST OUT datesArray[i] = Date()
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                result.setValue(Date(), forKey: "startDate")
                                // TEST OUT datesArray[i] = Date()
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            result.setValue(Date(), forKey: "startDate")
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        result.setValue(nil, forKey: "startDate")
                        // TEST OUT datesArray[i] = nil
                    }
                }
                i += 1
            }
        }

    }
    catch {

    }

    // tableView.reloadData()
    let indexPathsArray = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
    for indexPath in indexPathsArray! {

        var activity = ""

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TimersData")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            let results = try context.fetch(request)

            if results.count > 0 {
                if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

                    let result = (results as! [NSManagedObject])[indexPath.row]
                    if let activityIndicator = result.value(forKey: "activity") as? String {
                        activity = activityIndicator
                    }

                    var timerString = ""
                    var hourString = ""
                    var minuteString = ""
                    var secondString = ""
                    if let seconds = result.value(forKey: "timerSeconds") as? Int {
                        if let secondsLeftDouble = result.value(forKey: "timerProgress") as? Double {
                            let secondsLeft: Int = Int(floor(1*secondsLeftDouble)/1)
                            if seconds < 1 {
                            }
                            else if seconds >= 5 && seconds < 60 { // ss
                                timerString = "\(secondsLeft)s"
                            }
                            else if seconds >= 60 && seconds < 3600 { // mm:ss
                                let minute = secondsLeft / 60
                                minuteString = "\(minute)"
                                if minute < 10 {

                                    minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                                }
                                let second = secondsLeft % 60
                                var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                                if second < 10 {

                                    secondString = "0\(second)"

                                }
                                timerString = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"

                            }
                            else if seconds >= 3600 && seconds <= 86400 { // hh:mm:ss
                                let hourString: String = "\(secondsLeft / 3600)"
                                let minute = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60
                                var minuteString: String = "\(minute)"
                                if minute < 10 {

                                    minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                                }
                                let second = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60
                                var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                                if second < 10 {

                                    secondString = "0\(second)"

                                }
                                timerString = "\(hourString):\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var timerTitle = ""
                    if let title = result.value(forKey: "timerName") as? String {
                        timerTitle = title
                    }

                    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                    cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString, activityIndicator: activity, indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)

                    /* if activity == "active" {
                        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                        cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                        cell.sendIndexPath(indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
                    }
                    else if activity == "paused" {
                        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! pausedTableViewCell
                        cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                    }
                    else if activity == "none" {
                        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
                        cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                    }
                    else {
                        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
                        cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                    } */

                }
                else {
                    var i = 0
                    activeTimersArray = []
                    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                        if let activityIndicator = result.value(forKey: "activity") as? String {
                            if activityIndicator == "active" {
                                activeTimersArray.append(i)
                            }
                        }
                        i += 1
                    }

                    if indexPath.row < activeTimersArray.count {
                        let result = (results as! [NSManagedObject])[activeTimersArray[indexPath.row]]

                        var timerString = ""
                        var hourString = ""
                        var minuteString = ""
                        var secondString = ""
                        if let seconds = result.value(forKey: "timerSeconds") as? Int {
                            if let secondsLeftDouble = result.value(forKey: "timerProgress") as? Double {
                                let secondsLeft: Int = Int(round(secondsLeftDouble))
                                if seconds < 1 {
                                }
                                else if seconds >= 5 && seconds < 60 { // ss
                                    timerString = "\(secondsLeft)s"
                                }
                                else if seconds >= 60 && seconds < 3600 { // mm:ss
                                    let minute = secondsLeft / 60
                                    minuteString = "\(minute)"
                                    if minute < 10 {

                                        minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                                    }
                                    let second = secondsLeft % 60
                                    var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                                    if second < 10 {

                                        secondString = "0\(second)"

                                    }
                                    timerString = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"

                                }
                                else if seconds >= 3600 && seconds <= 86400 { // hh:mm:ss
                                    let hourString: String = "\(secondsLeft / 3600)"
                                    let minute = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60
                                    var minuteString: String = "\(minute)"
                                    if minute < 10 {

                                        minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                                    }
                                    let second = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60
                                    var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                                    if second < 10 {

                                        secondString = "0\(second)"

                                    }
                                    timerString = "\(hourString):\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        var timerTitle = ""
                        if let title = result.value(forKey: "timerName") as? String {
                            timerTitle = title
                        }

                        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                        cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString, activityIndicator: "active", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
                    }
                    else {
                        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                        cell.configureCell(name: "Processing", time: "Processing", activityIndicator: "active", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
                    }


                }

            }
            else {
                // let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
                // cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error")
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error", activityIndicator: "none", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
            }
        }
        catch {
            // let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
            // cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error")

            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
            cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error", activityIndicator: "none", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

**Code for TableView data source:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var noRows = 0

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TimersData")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            noRows = results.count
        }
        else {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let activityIndicator = result.value(forKey: "activity") as? String {
                    if activityIndicator == "active" {
                        noRows += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch {

    }

    return noRows
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var activity = ""

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TimersData")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

                let result = (results as! [NSManagedObject])[indexPath.row]
                if let activityIndicator = result.value(forKey: "activity") as? String {
                    activity = activityIndicator
                }

                var timerString = ""
                var hourString = ""
                var minuteString = ""
                var secondString = ""
                if let seconds = result.value(forKey: "timerSeconds") as? Int {
                    if let secondsLeftDouble = result.value(forKey: "timerProgress") as? Double {
                        let secondsLeft: Int = Int(round(secondsLeftDouble))
                        if seconds < 1 {
                        }
                        else if seconds >= 5 && seconds < 60 { // ss
                            timerString = "\(secondsLeft)s"
                        }
                        else if seconds >= 60 && seconds < 3600 { // mm:ss
                            let minute = secondsLeft / 60
                            minuteString = "\(minute)"
                            if minute < 10 {

                                minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                            }
                            let second = secondsLeft % 60
                            var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                            if second < 10 {

                                secondString = "0\(second)"

                            }
                            timerString = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"

                        }
                        else if seconds >= 3600 && seconds <= 86400 { // hh:mm:ss
                            let hourString: String = "\(secondsLeft / 3600)"
                            let minute = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60
                            var minuteString: String = "\(minute)"
                            if minute < 10 {

                                minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                            }
                            let second = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60
                            var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                            if second < 10 {

                                secondString = "0\(second)"

                            }
                            timerString = "\(hourString):\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
                        }
                    }
                }

                var timerTitle = ""
                if let title = result.value(forKey: "timerName") as? String {
                    timerTitle = title
                }

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "active", for: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString, activityIndicator: activity, indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
                return cell

                /* if activity == "active" {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "active", for: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                    cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                    return cell
                }
                else if activity == "paused" {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "paused", for: indexPath) as! pausedTableViewCell
                    cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                    return cell
                }
                else if activity == "none" {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inactive", for: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
                    cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                    return cell
                }
                else {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inactive", for: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
                    cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString)
                    return cell
                } */

            }
            else {
                var i = 0
                activeTimersArray = []
                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                    if let activityIndicator = result.value(forKey: "activity") as? String {
                        if activityIndicator == "active" {
                            activeTimersArray.append(i)
                        }
                    }
                    i += 1
                }

                if indexPath.row < activeTimersArray.count {
                    let result = (results as! [NSManagedObject])[activeTimersArray[indexPath.row]]

                    var timerString = ""
                    var hourString = ""
                    var minuteString = ""
                    var secondString = ""
                    if let seconds = result.value(forKey: "timerSeconds") as? Int {
                        if let secondsLeftDouble = result.value(forKey: "timerProgress") as? Double {
                            let secondsLeft: Int = Int(round(secondsLeftDouble))
                            if seconds < 1 {
                            }
                            else if seconds >= 5 && seconds < 60 { // ss
                                timerString = "\(secondsLeft)s"
                            }
                            else if seconds >= 60 && seconds < 3600 { // mm:ss
                                let minute = secondsLeft / 60
                                minuteString = "\(minute)"
                                if minute < 10 {

                                    minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                                }
                                let second = secondsLeft % 60
                                var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                                if second < 10 {

                                    secondString = "0\(second)"

                                }
                                timerString = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"

                            }
                            else if seconds >= 3600 && seconds <= 86400 { // hh:mm:ss
                                let hourString: String = "\(secondsLeft / 3600)"
                                let minute = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60
                                var minuteString: String = "\(minute)"
                                if minute < 10 {

                                    minuteString = "0\(minute)"

                                }
                                let second = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60
                                var secondString: String = "\(second)"
                                if second < 10 {

                                    secondString = "0\(second)"

                                }
                                timerString = "\(hourString):\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var timerTitle = ""
                    if let title = result.value(forKey: "timerName") as? String {
                        timerTitle = title
                    }

                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "active", for: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                    cell.configureCell(name: timerTitle, time: timerString, activityIndicator: "active", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
                    return cell
                }
                else {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "active", for: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
                    cell.configureCell(name: "Processing", time: "Processing", activityIndicator: "active", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
                    return cell
                }


            }

        }
        else {
            /* let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inactive", for: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
            cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error")
            return cell */

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "active", for: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
            cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error", activityIndicator: "none", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
            return cell
        }
    }
    catch {
        /* let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inactive", for: indexPath) as! nonactiveTableViewCell
        cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error")
        return cell */

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "active", for: indexPath) as! activeTableViewCell
        cell.configureCell(name: "Error", time: "Error", activityIndicator: "none", indexPathToSend: indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Ignore any comments - they are just me trying to fix other problems.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code that updates your cells

Comment: cant help without code. Add your tableView dataSource methods and also let us know how do you trigger reload cell/tableView

Comment: I have added reloading cells will now add for data source

Comment: this is a crazy content every 0.25

Comment: @Sh_Khan do you have any other suggestions for updating the multiple timers smoothly?

Comment: @Caypilot Update the view inside the cell class, not refresh the table

Comment: @Tj3n I am not refreshing the table the tableView.reloadData() is commented out from when I realised the problems it was causing

Comment: @Paulw11 are you able to help?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari are you able to help?

Comment: Don't fetch the objects each time. Fetch them once and store them in an array. Each time the timer fires, iterate the visible rows in the tableview and update the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data saves records unordered for performance reasons.

If you want a specific order you need to apply an appropriate sort descriptor

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TimersData")
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"startDate", ascending: true)]
```

Replace `startDate` with the desired attribute name.

No comment about the questionable necessity to fetch Core Data objects 4 times a second and in each call of `cellForRow`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Just about to try it with orderID - If you hadn't answered I would have ended up wasting so much time writing the sort core myself; will tick if works! Thanks :)